# How to get Live Edit to work with Pycharm 5

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, pycharm, liveedit

When I try to use a Javascript debug configuration to use the Live Edit function of PyCharm 5 the IDE starts a browser tab, which seems like it connects to the IDE but nothing works.

There is no error either. I found no documentation of this anywhere online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support told me that you have to install an old version of the Live Edit plugin in PyCharm. What works is **LiveEdit V2.0.18.143** which you can find **[here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7007?pr=idea)**. So far there was no google-able information about this and I spent ours trying to figure it out. Hopefully the next person will find this here.

Comment: your post helped me save sanity (after losing many hours :). Very sad on the side of pycharm people not posting this information anywhere on their documentation..